# Как сгенерировать таблицу функции двух и более переменных?

Tags: python, numpy

Имеется функция двух переменных, требуется составить таблицу значений этой функции при различных значениях параметров. Сначала я создаю массивы параметров:

```
x1 = np.linspace(5, 95, 10)
x2 = np.linspace(3200, 2600, 50)
x1_grid, x2_grid = np.meshgrid(x1, x2)
```

Затем создаю массив, содержащий искомую таблицу:

```
y = np.zeros(x1_grid.shape)
```

Теперь заполняю его значениями:

```
for (index1, x1), (index2, x2) in zip(np.ndenumerate(x1_grid), np.ndenumerate(x2_grid)):
    y[index1] = calc(x1, x2)
```

Последнее действие, вероятно, можно сделать проще. Как? Возможно, есть какие-то приёмы работы с meshgrid, которые я не знаю. В дальнейшем планируется масштабировать вычисления на функции большего количества параметров (до 5). Так же их соединять через `zip` или есть вариант проще?

---

**UPD** Интересует не оптимизация по времени, а питоновские трюки, которые помогут записать последний цикл короче и понятнее, избегая неиспользуемые итераторы, что станет более актуально, когда размерность пространства повысится.

Comment: а функция категорически не хочет принимать numpy массивы в качестве аргументов?

Comment: Покажите вашу функцию `calc`, может проще её в "векторизованном виде" написать, чем аргументы по одному перебирать.

Comment: @CrazyElf, она довольно глубокая, но вкратце - там активно применяются численные методы (`scipy.optimize.minimize`, `scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar`). [см. CalcNessesaryC3](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1tYPDwzDd0QjhKo98TYUYQhG41vyrfXdO?usp=sharing)

Comment: Если саму функцию `calc` векторизовывать, то нужно, чтобы все входящие в неё функции тоже были векторизованы. А это не так. Иначе тело функции превратится в того же монстра, что в последнем блоке кода.

Comment: Ну, я смотрю оно работает за вполне приемлемое время. Может и не нужно ничего тогда оптимизировать?

Comment: Вопрос не в оптимизации по времени, а в избегании нагромождений кода при наращивании размерности пространства. Сейчас у меня используется объединение двух итераторов в zip, `index2` фактически не используется, так как равен `index1`. Но что будет, если размерность повысится до 5? Этот код разрастётся в объёмного монстра. Поэтому меня интересуют питоновские трюки, с помощью которых этот цикл можно записать короче и понятнее.

Comment: `for index, l in enumerate(zip(a,b,c)): y[index] = calc(*l)`

Comment: @splash58, так в функцию `calc` попадают последовательно массивы `(x1_grid[0,:], x2_grid[0,:])`, `(x1_grid[1,:], x2_grid[1,:])` и т.д. А должны попасть отдельно каждые элементы массивов: `(x1_grid[0,0], x2_grid[0,0])`, `(x1_grid[0, 1], x2_grid[0, 1])` и т.д.

Comment: А что zip не разберет их поэлементно?